# Set maximum bubble size for Google Sheets bubble chart

Tags: google-sheets, data-visualization

Setting a size column seems only to change the relative size. I'd like to shrink all the bubbles. Is that possible?

Answer (score 0):

To delimit a maximum bubble size in the Sheets API you would have to set the property `sizeAxis.maxSize`. You can also set the minimum size to shrink the bubbles even more by setting `sizeAxis.minSize`. [Here](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/bubblechart) you can learn more about how to configure Charts, read [this](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/spreadsheets) to integrate them into Sheets.